# SSRS how do you repeat a header row in a list?

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I'm trying to repeat a row header and it's not working... I've tried following all posts and documentation.  Any ideas???

[image]

Basically everything on the same row as RackID I want to repeat on the next page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to this.  ALL static members within the SAME group must have repeat on new page set to TRUE.  Then you can modify the other properties like keep with group etc. to decide what else you want to repeat.